# How to mention all attributes in single line

Tags: javascript, attributes

How to mention all attributes in single line :)

```
document.getElementById("image").src = "landscape.jpg";
document.getElementById("image").width = "300";
document.getElementById("image").height = "300";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in one line, with JavaScript; you can, though, abbreviate to *two*:

```
document.getElementById("image").src = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife/3";
document.getElementById("image").width = document.getElementById("image").height = "300";
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/65pxqkdh/).

Though, honestly, I'm not sure that you gain anything.

Of course, if you choose efficiency (albeit a micro-optimisation), you go back to three lines again by caching the result of `document.getElementById()`:

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');
image.src = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife/3";
image.width = image.height = "300";
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/65pxqkdh/1/).

It is possible in most, if not *all*, browsers to use the automagic global variables assigned by the browser, to map a reference to an element with an `id` property to a variable of that name (an element with `id="image"` is available under a global variable `image`):

```
image.src = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife/3";
image.width = image.height = "300";
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/65pxqkdh/2/).

It is, however, worth noting that while the automagic variables are a possibility, their use is not advisable: global variables, especially in large code-bases or with multiple contributors, are prone to errors and misuse. And, as noted in the comments below, their use is, or may be, deprecated (reference: [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)).

All the above was used with the following HTML:

```
<img src="" id="image" />
```

Comment: Cannot agree with suggesting use of the "automagic global variables". This usage is widely deprecated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables.

Comment: Don't misunderstand me, my mention of the possibility is *not* my recommending the practice; I'd be glad to see the back of this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can also save a variable white the element, so you don't have to do document.getElementById each time

```
var img = document.getElementById("image");
img.src = "landscape.jpg";
img.width = img.height = "300";
```

you could also make a function the be able to in one line later

```
function setValues(element, props){
    for(var key in props){
        element[key] = props[key];
    }
}

setValues(document.getElementById("image"), {src: "landscape.jpg", width:"300", height:"300"});
```

If you need to do a lot of dom manipulation, you could look at a framework like jQuery and zepto, but this becomes overkill, if this is the only thing you need to change.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
with(document.getElementById("image")) { src = "landscape.jpg"; width = "300"; height = "300"; }
```

Or use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$("#image").attr("src", "landscape.jpg").width(300).height(300);
// or
$("#image").attr("src", "landscape.jpg").attr("width": "300").attr("height": "300");
// or
$("#image").attr("src", "landscape.jpg").css({ "width": "300px", "height": "300px" });
```

Comment: Do not suggest the use of `with`. Among other problems, it is not supported in strict mode. Also, questions which do not mention jQuery or specify the jQuery tag should not be answered with jQuery solutions unless it has been confirmed with the OP via a comment that he or she is amenable to a jQuery approach.